# Models and roles in Qt5 and Qt 4.8

Tags: qt, models, qml, porting, qt5

Today I wanted to play with QtQuick2 a little bit. So I have started to port very simple Qt Quick1 app to Quick2. This app uses some models. And in Qt5 models are not working as I expect: I can't access data using roles.

This is my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
width: 800
height: 360

ListView {
    model: mainModel
    spacing: 5
    anchors.fill: parent
    orientation: ListView.Vertical
    delegate: Text {
        text: "1"

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log(mainModel);
            console.log(mainModel.roles() );
            console.log(model);
            console.log(model.homm); // `homm` is my roleName
            console.log(homm);
        }
    }
```

In Qt4.8 I was able to get data using `roleName` syntax (in this QML my roleName=`homm`) but in Qt5 I can't. That's what is written in console:

```
MainModel(0x7fff08beff80)
homm,wtf
QQuickVDMAbstractItemModelData(0x23c96e0)
undefined
file:///media/disk/kakadu/prog/qt/quick2test/qml/quick2test/main.qml:20: ReferenceError: homm is not defined
```

And that's for Quick 1.1

```
MainModel(0x7fffe58182f0)
undefined
QDeclarativeVisualDataModelData(0x2372ea0)
QVariant(MiniModel*)
QVariant(MiniModel*)
```

As you can see accessing data using roles work as expected. I have created test apps for you:
[for Qt5](https://github.com/Kakadu/qml-test-2/tree/88b2f33d7b06f41b44601d9387b8a0046731fa3f) and [for Qt 4.8](https://github.com/Kakadu/qml-test-2/tree/88b2f33d7b06f41b44601d9387b8a0046731fa3f). I hope  you will help me to find the heart of matter.

P.S. I have made some changes in Qt5 version. In Qt5 method `setRoleNames()` is obsolete and overriding of `roleNames()` is recommended. I have done this overriding.

P.P.S. My code example should be compilable on GNU/Linux x64

Comment: Your Qt5 code does not compile.

Comment: trollixx, If your are talking about `'MiniModel' : illegal member initialization` It didn't know that. I was tested that on GNU/Linux x64. I need some time to investigate what is wrong in MSVC compiler.

Comment: Ubuntu Linux x86_64, g++ 4.6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a mistake in your code. `roleNames()` is constant method. Here's a working line of code:

```
virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const { return _roles; }
```

There's a working example too: examples/quick/modelviews/abstractitemmodel.