# Create a ListView with dynamic parameters in QML

Tags: qt, listview, dynamic, qml

is there a method to create a ListView with dynamic parameters (for example for the model?)

I want to create this qml item dynamically:

```
Item{
id:item
    ListView{
        id:listitem
        spacing: 5
        width:list.width
        height:list.height/3
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        model: imageModelX //variablename is dynamic
        delegate: Delegate{
            ....
       }
      }
```

}

Best regards

Comment: I have seen your previous (already deleted) question. Why you don't want to create model which returns inner models in some role?

Comment: Can I do this? I've test it last time, but the program is crashed. I will test it again.

Comment: I will try to find some code example....

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/Kakadu/qml-test-2

Comment: thank you! QVariant::fromValue(model) is the trick for the inner model

Comment: Can I copy and paste it to answer to give you opportunity to accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved similar problem by adding to main model role that returns inner models.
Code is here: https://github.com/Kakadu/qml-test-2

Comment: mhnm, now i checked it with an older version of QT (4.8.4). There the inner model doesn't work. The qml can't find the references to the model item [`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: autoRating`]. Is there a fix for it?

Comment: No idea, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031462/models-and-roles-in-qt5-and-qt-4-8 will be useful?

Comment: I found a solution. in the `data()`, i cast my Model to a QObject*: `return QVariant::fromValue((QObject* )model);` that's the trick.